# Replacing 10th column in file1 with the content of 10th column in file2

Tags: command-line, awk

I have two files which content are:

File 1:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEU     1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  1.00      PROT
```

File 2:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  2.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  5.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEUUUU  1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  3.00      PROT
```

Output file:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  5.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEUUUU  1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  1.00      PROT
```

I want to replace the content of the 10th column of file 2 with the content of 10th column in file 1

My first try was:

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$10;next}{$10=a[FNR]}1' file2 file1
```

What I get is that all the content of file 2 is completly replaced by the content of file 1.

Comment: Do you actually have tabs in the files?

Comment: @muru No, but I need the output with tabs

Comment: That's a different problem. With `-F "\t"` you're telling awk that the input comes with tabs. Output is set via `OFS`.

Comment: @muru True, would you give me an applied example of _OFS_ to this case?

Comment: Just change `-F "\t"` to `-v OFS="\t"`

Comment: @muru Thank you, it worked!

Comment: @muru what would you recommend me to keep the original spacing? any other command line?  (The program does not read the file with tab spacing)